# JQuery drag&move but leave the original if CTRL key is pressed?

Tags: jquery

I have the following JQuery code to drag&drop to change ul item orders (#list ul). How can I make it if the CTRL key is pressed, drag&move but leave the original ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
function slideout(){
setTimeout(function(){
$("#res").slideUp("slow", function () {
      });

}, 2000);}

    $("#res").hide();
    $(function() {
    $("#list ul").sortable({ opacity: 0.4, cursor: 'move', update: function() {

            var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&update=update';
            $("#hload").fadeIn('fast');
            $.post("upd.php", order, function(theResponse){
                $("#res").html(theResponse);
                $("#res").slideDown('slow');
                $("#hload").fadeOut('fast');
                slideout();

            });
        }
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

Thank You.

Comment: you want to leave D&D when CTRL pressed?

Comment: Vury, I want to leave the original #list ul item when pressed CTRL instead of moving it.

Comment: I mean drag and drop the item but copy the item if CTRL is pressed instead of moving it. Lets say I have 3 items below;

item 1
item 2
item 3

If I press CTRL then drag&drop the item 3, leave the item 3 there but copy it so the list will be

item 3
item 1
item 2
item 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, set a variable when the Ctrl key is down.

```
var ctrlDown = false;
$(window).on("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.which === 17) {
        ctrlDown = true;
    }
}).on("keyup", function(event) {
    ctrlDown = false;
});
```

Then, clone your item if ctrlDown is true.

```
$(".sortable").sortable({start: function( event, ui ) {
    if (ctrlDown) {
        $clone = ui.item.clone().insertBefore(ui.item);
        $clone.css({position:"static"});
    }
}});
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iGanja/jjhJT/2/)

In the Fiddle you need to click in the window before the keydown and keyup events will work.

**EDIT**: I will leave the original for posterity, but wow, this was so much easier than originally made out to be by simply using the ctrlKey property of the event object.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".sortable").sortable({start: function( event, ui ) {
        if (event.ctrlKey){
            $clone = ui.item.clone().insertBefore(ui.item);
            $clone.css({position:"static"});
        }
    }});
});
```

[New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iGanja/jjhJT/3/)

Comment: @user2228185 OMG, I can't believe I did not remember the event object has a ctrlKey property! Please see my revised answer.

Comment: Great approach, however I see the second solution won't cancel the drag/copy if the user releases the Ctrl key, so there is no way for them to cancel the operation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle I came up with that will move items between multiple lists but leave the original if the Ctrl pressed.

```
      $(".connectedSortable" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        helper: function(e,li) {
              copyHelper= li.clone().insertAfter(li);
              return li.clone();
         },
        stop: function() {
              copyHelper && copyHelper.remove();
        },
        receive: function(event, ui) {
            if (event.ctrlKey){
                copyHelper= null;
            }
            var myOrder = {};
            $(".sortable ul").each(function() {
                var key = $(this).attr("data-name");
                myOrder[key] = [];
                $(this).find('li').each(function(){
                    myOrder[key].push($(this).attr("data-key"));
                });
            });
            var arr = JSON.stringify(myOrder);
            $('#field_mappings').val(arr);
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n92e5e2r/10/